# Selenium send keys is not working

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, testng

I currently have a selenium project (Java with TestNG driving it) testing a AngularJS website. I have been working with selenium for about 1 year so I am familiar with most aspects of the framework however I am stumped on a basic issue. I have a basic input field in which I am trying to send information to using sendKeys. For some reason the information is not being input into the element. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will add that I have no proble entering the information on other input fields on other pages.

**Input element:**

```
<input id="input-info-company-name" type="text" ng-model="vm.groupData.name" required="" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched md-input ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

**Selenium code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("input-info-company-name")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("input-info-company-name")).sendKeys(groupInfo.getCompanyName() + driver.getClass().getSimpleName());
```

When I use the clear before sending the keys I get the following stacktrace

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it
```

If I remove the clear and just sendKeys I receive no error but have no values entered in the input field.

Any help is greatly appreciated and If you need any more information please let me know

Comment: Are you sure this is the only element with `id="input-info-company-name"` on the page?

Comment: @alecxeYes and it is definitely the first instance of it so it would be the one used either way

Comment: Okay, what if you would click it before clearing?

Comment: @alecxe I had the same idea but unfortunately there was no change in functionality

Comment: What if you would, just for the debugging purposes, add an artificial delay with `Thread.sleep()` before calling `clear()`?

Comment: @alecxe So you're thinking it may be some parts of the page not loaded yet. I will give this a try

Comment: Yeah, the idea behind it is that the input is an some sort of an intermediate state while angular being not ready to be interacted with..

Comment: @alecxe No change. I am currently running with the Firefox driver so I will try with chrome and see if anything changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having is that the ID was being used on the page, above that input element. So I was trying to clear a container. Thanks to @alecxe for pointing this out. I will leave this thread up in case somebody has the same issue